# How to write Unit test for main static method in Main class?

Tags: java, testing, methods, junit, service

I have want to write unit test to test methods in Main class. However, I don't know how to handle with the parameter **String[] args** in main method. Moreover, when I extract the static function like menuForBill, I can not extract it directly from class Main by Main.menuForBill and I really don't know why.

**Main method in main class like this:**

```
public static void menuForBill(Bill bill, Menu menu) throws IOException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String option="0";
        BillServices billServices = new BillServicesImpl();
        BillFileHandlingServices billFileHandlingServices = new BillFileHandlingServicesImpl();
        BillPrinter billPrinter = new BillPrinterImpl();

        while (!option.equals("e")){
            System.out.println("\nBill management");
            System.out.println("1. Create Bill ");
            System.out.println("2. Update Bill ");
            System.out.println("3. Delete Bill");
            System.out.println("4. Show Bill");
            System.out.println("5. Export bill");
            System.out.println("6. Import bill");
            System.out.println("e. To escape");
            System.out.print("\nChoose your option:");
            option = scanner.next();
            switch (option){
                case "1" -> billServices.addBill(bill,menu);
                case "2" -> billServices.updateBill(bill,menu);
                case "3" -> billServices.deleteBillItems(bill);
                case "4" -> {try {
                    billPrinter.printBill(bill);
                }catch (NullPointerException exception){
                    System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
                }}
                case "5" -> billFileHandlingServices.exportBill(bill);
                case "6" -> billFileHandlingServices.importBill();
                case "e" -> {}
                default -> System.out.println("Not found for your option !!!");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String option;
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        Bill bill = new Bill();
        while (true){
            System.out.println("\n1.Menu management");
            System.out.println("2.Bill management");
            System.out.print("Please choose which types Management you want to work with:");
            option = scanner.next();

            switch (option){
                case "1" -> menuForOrder(menu);
                case "2" -> menuForBill(bill,menu);
                default -> System.out.println("Out of option !!!");
            }
        }
    }
```

**My unit test:**

```
public class MainTest {
    private final InputStream systemIn = System.in;
    private final PrintStream systemOut = System.out;

    private ByteArrayInputStream testIn;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream testOut;
    @Rule
    public final TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock = emptyStandardInputStream();

    @Before
    public void init(){
        testOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(testOut));
    }

    @After
    public void restoreSystemInputOutput(){
        System.setIn(systemIn);
        System.setOut(systemOut);
    }

    @Test
    public void whenChoosingMenuManagement_returnMenuManagement() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("main");
        systemInMock.provideLines("1");
        Main.main(new String[]{"a"});
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

**The error:**

```
error: Class names, 'a', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
1 error
```

How I can write unit for main method and menuForBill method in this case. I am beginner in Unit test. Thanks for your support.

Comment: why do you use @Rule for something that should be a mock? what is the unit you are trying to test?

Comment: I use the System Rules to pass in the user input from the Java.lang.System . And about the unit test I am trying to test main method and other methods in Main class to see if it works like I expected or not.

Comment: this is more an integration test, compared to a unit test. You hardly have any units, and since they're all void methods, it's pretty hard to test anything

Comment: And I don't know why I couldn't call static method like menuForBill directly from class Main.

Comment: Seeing as you are calling it directly, I don't understand your question here.

Comment: That error message is from javac. How are you building your code?